# MYSQL Select MAX COUNT in DATE RANGE

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, count, max

I was looking to a lot of examples, but I couldn't find an answer. What I need to do is check if there is free space for new orders. In one time I can have maximum 5 customers. Order duration is not limited, customers just selects date-time range in picker.

For example my DB records are:

```
`id` `start`            `end`
`1`  `2017/06/10 10:00` `2017/06/15 08:00`
`2`  `2017/06/11 10:00` `2017/06/16 08:00`
`3`  `2017/06/12 10:00` `2017/06/17 08:00`
`4`  `2017/06/13 10:00` `2017/06/18 08:00`
`5`  `2017/06/14 10:00` `2017/06/19 08:00`
```

Customer want to reserve from 2017/06/11 08:00 until 2017/06/15 12:00, but I can't let him because this period coincides with more than 5 records in my DB. How can I do it in mysql select query?

Comment: Performance matters? What is the minimum slot granularity? One hour? One minute? A second? Can you be more polite on your comments? I read your answer's comments, you look rude, may be is a language issue but you should to take care about people who is helping or trying to help you.

Comment: So (omitting time and year for brevity), if there are individual non-overlapping records for 6/1, 6/2, 6/3, 6/4, and 6/5; would a reservation requested for 6/1 to 6/5 be permitted?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Select count(*)>5 as vacant
From orders
Where (input_start < end and input_start>start ) or
(Input_end > start and input start<start)
```

Where `input` are your search values

Comment: This solution is wrong when I have bigger duration and capacity.

Answer (score 0):

You can do count the number of matching records using logic like this:

```
select count(*)
from t
where $start < end and $end > start;
```

This counts the number of records that overlap with ($start, $end).  You can put the comparison to "5" in your application.  (Or just use `select count(*) < 5`.

Note:  You should be passing in the values as parameters.

Comment: You need a more accurate select. If you have 4 bookings by day in a 5 days range your select returns 20, but, they are space for the 5th booking each day. (In my opinion)

Comment: This solution is wrong when I have bigger duration and capacity.

Comment: @Xinel . . . I have no idea why you think this is wrong.  I read the question and this is the logic that gets 5 overlaps during the time period.  Perhaps your question is not what you intend to ask.

Comment: @Xinel, you should to split your range in minimum granularity and invoke the query for each slot. If performance matters then you should to be more verbose on your question. Also explain about slots and slot granularity. And try to be more polite on your comments, you look like a little rude man.

Answer (score 0):

Try likethis :

```
select id from table where id not in 
/*the query below will get the wrong result */
(select id from table where yourstartdate between start and end or yourenddate between start and end);
```

Comment: This solution is wrong when I have bigger duration and capacity.

Comment: You say is wrong maybe because the duration takes alot of time for the execution ? as i think is not the solution who is wrong but maybe you should think to put some index in your table  to make it more performant

Answer (score 0):

There are many, *many* solutions. You've tagged this as PHP so there is scope to do this in the application logic as well as one the storage.

You could separate the 5 slots across attributes (which are constrained by definition) rather than across rows (which are not constrained). Then let the application decide if the transaction is viable (although you could map this to a single slot-per-record representation using views and triggers).

While as others have suggested, you could count the number of slots currently booked to determine if there is availability (but this would need be done at least twice and you need to avoid race conditions). For preference this would be implemented as a before-insert trigger.

An alternative approach or enhancement to this would be to add a primary/unique key to the table containing the reservations including an enumerated column (with 5 possible values and a non-null constraint) making it impossible to inject more than 5 records for one slot.

But this is all about preventing a state which is considered inconsistent. Your first line of defence is presenting the user with options which are unlikely to cause such conflicts. The obvious case is not to present slots which already have 5 bookings.